# C# Predicatebuilder gives error on double word

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, linqkit

I have an algorithm for searcing text under a pagination endpoint like
"http://localhost:8001/api/endusers?count=20&offset=0&**search=mert ozan,FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,Email,CompanyName**"

So, My code takes **"mert ozan"** as a **searchText**, and other fields are our search target. This searchText **gives correct result with only one sentence like "mert"** finds mert in any cases. But if searchText is **"mert ozan" it does not work.** What should I change for this situation?

Here is my code block:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
{
    var searchParams = search.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries);
    if (searchParams.Length > 1)
    {
        var searchText = searchParams.First();
        var searchFields = searchParams.Where((_, index) => index != 0).ToList();

        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<AdminEnduserPaginationView>();
        searchFields.ForEach((x) =>
        {
            predicate = predicate.Or(p => EF.Functions.Like(EF.Property<string>(p, x), searchText + "%"));
        });

        endUserQuery = endUserQuery.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

**What I Tried:**

I attempted to search using a multi-field query with "mert ozan" as the searchText.

**Expected Outcome:**

I expected the code to correctly retrieve results for "mert ozan" in any of the specified search fields.
**
Actual Result:**

The code worked for single words (e.g., "mert") but failed for the full "mert ozan." It doesn't handle multi-word searches as expected. Looking for guidance to make it work correctly.

Comment: Have you looked at the string in the debugger? Are you sure you're not getting the HTML encoded string which would use `+` or `%20` for the space?

Comment: @DStanley Sir, i did not understand exactly. Actually, it is a backend issue. I've been trying it with postman. Of course, now front-end search doesnt work

Comment: How can you verify that the the backend uses the string with a space in it? URLs (including any query parameters) cannot contain spaces, so they are encoded to either a `+` or `%20`. The backend may not be decoding the string property to turn it back to a space. You can't tell that from the client - you have to either run it in a debugger to view the variables or add logging to print the exact string it gets.

Comment: side note: this `var searchFields = searchParams.Where((_, index) => index != 0).ToList();` could just be `var searchFields = searchParams.Skip(1);`